# After restoring sqlite database, old file stays active??

Tags: android, sqlite, backup, restore

I have a restore option in my app, which reads in the back-up file, and copies it over the original sqlite-db.

Everything seems to work fine, except for the fact that after the restore, the old db-file is still active. If I shut down my application completely, using `System.exit(0);`, it does load the restored database, and everything works as expected.

It seems that the application keeps the old db-file in RAM, although that seems odd ...

Below the code:

```
             File dbFile = new File(DatabaseHelper.DB_PATH + DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME);
             if (dbFile.exists()) {
                Boolean fileDeleted = dbFile.delete();
                Log.i(DatabaseHelper.LOG_TAG, "fileDeleted: " + String.valueOf(fileDeleted));
                }

             try {
                Log.i(DatabaseHelper.LOG_TAG, "myDatabase.isOpen: " + String.valueOf(dbHelper.myDataBase.isOpen()));
                dbHelper.cleanup();
                Log.i(DatabaseHelper.LOG_TAG, "myDatabase.isOpen: " + String.valueOf(dbHelper.myDataBase.isOpen()));
                Boolean newFileCreated = dbFile.createNewFile();
                Log.i(DatabaseHelper.LOG_TAG, "newFileCreated: " + String.valueOf(newFileCreated));
                FileUtil.copyFile(dbBackupFile, dbFile);
                return null;
             } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(DatabaseHelper.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                return e.getMessage();
             }
```

Somebody experienced the same?

I did check to see if some activity has the db open, but as far as I can see, this is nowhere the case. All the log-entries show expected/correct values ...

I've tried everything, so any suggestions/ideas are very much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Greetingz,
Koen Hoorelbeke<

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `System.exit(0)`, use `finish()`. Which will `finish()` the activity and GC will take care of the memory, and you'll be a step forward to solution. I think it takes some time before the file is deleted, I've notice it on the emulator. Are you copying the database from any folder (raw/assets)?

I suggest you to  try `close()` or`releaseMemory()` the database before you do the copying stuff of the old one and the new one. And then reassign to the db object the new database file